# Two's complement arithmetic proof

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, binary

Can anyone prove that groups $G:=({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},+)$ and $H:=({0,1,2,3,-4,-3,-2,-1},+)$ are isomorphic with the bijection which is `two's complement` and `+` meaning `modulo 8 addition`? I mean, the fact that `two's complement` is a bijection is obvious but it's not obvious that $2c(a+b)=2c(a)+2c(b)$ for any a and b from $G$ or $H$.
What I want is basically proof of validity of two's complement arithmetics.
And I'm new to group theory (only wikipedia basics). TY.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax

Answer (score 1):

Ok, both groups are isomorphic to $Z_8$, and $2c$ just makes the correct bijection between numbers representing corresponding `congruence classes`. This is not a rigid proof but that pretty much clears out the situation.